# Converting from handlebars to vue.js - using a pseduo root element

Tags: handlebars.js, vue.js

I have the following handlebars template:

```
{{#each this}}
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="respondent">Respondent #{{respondent_id}}</td>
</tr>
{{#each questions}}
<tr>
    <td>{{question}}</td>
    <td>{{answers}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

I want to try Vue.js, but it's not clear to me from the docs how to do this. Essentially, the parent list gets 1 `<tr>` for its main properties and then a list of children `<tr>`s for every question in the questions property.

Suggestions for doing this with vue.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question, you may want something like this:

```
<div id="demo">
  <table border="1">
    <template v-for="respondent in respondents">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="respondent">Respondent #{{respondent.id}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="q in respondent.questions">
        <td>{{q.question}}</td>
        <td>{{q.answer}}</td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </table>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    respondents: [
      {
        id: 1,
        questions: [
          { question: '1st Question (#1)', answer: '1st Answer (#1)' },
          { question: '2nd Question (#1)', answer: '2nd Answer (#1)' }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        questions: [
          { question: '1st Question (#2)', answer: '1st Answer (#2)' },
          { question: '2nd Question (#2)', answer: '2nd Answer (#2)' }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        questions: [
          { question: '1st Question (#3)', answer: '1st Answer (#3)' },
          { question: '2nd Question (#3)', answer: '2nd Answer (#3)' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

http://codepen.io/pespantelis/pen/QjoLLK

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I just discovered the <template/> element myself and was coming back to answer my own question. Looks like you get the credit instead! :)